# how to avoid space on newline while joining a list

Tags: python

```
newContents = ['The', 'crazy', 'panda', 'walked', 'to', 'the', 'Maulik', 'and', 'then', 'picked.', 'A', 'nearby', 'Ankur', 'was\n', 'unaffected', 'by', 'these', 'events.\n']
print(' '.join(newContents))
```

output:

```
The crazy panda walked to the Maulik and then picked. A nearby Ankur was
 unaffected by these events.
```

there is space before the (first) word *unaffected* on second line I don't want a space there.

Comment: You want to keep the new line?

Comment: yes. Just don't want the space before first word of a line.

Comment: `print(' '.join(map(lambda s: s.strip(), newContents)))`

Comment: there's no spaces, only newlines

Comment: It removes newline @ewcz

Comment: space is before the word unaffected in output (on second line). @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: print(' '.join(newContents).replace('\n ', '\n')

Comment: @PiotrKamoda, it worked. thanks.

Comment: @gonduriya lots of answers appeared, but I explained ;)

Comment: @gonduriya yes, indeed, sorry - I misunderstood the question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simple enough solution: replace `\n[space]` with `\n`. That way all spaces are left alone and only string replaced is `\n[space]` with newline without space

```
>>> newContents = ['The', 'crazy', 'panda', 'walked', 'to', 'the', 'Maulik', 'and', 'then', 'picked.', 'A', 'nearby', 'Ankur', 'was\n', 'unaffected', 'by', 'these', 'events.\n']
>>> print(' '.join(newContents).replace('\n ', '\n'))
The crazy panda walked to the Maulik and then picked. A nearby Ankur was
unaffected by these events.
```

Answer (score 3):

You could remove it after join:

```
your_string = ' '.join(newContents).replace('\n ', '\n')
print(your_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to check for a space after a newline:

```
print(' '.join(newContents).replace('\n ', '\n'))
```

It outputs :

```
The crazy panda walked to the Maulik and then picked. A nearby Ankur was
unaffected by these events.
```

Comment: This will also remove the new line.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: lol we wrote (except for the ellipse) exactly the same text at exactly the same moment...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem possible duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Use [***re.sub***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function to remove spaces right after newline:

```
import re

newContents = ['The', 'crazy', 'panda', 'walked', 'to', 'the', 'Maulik', 'and', 'then', 'picked.', 'A', 'nearby', 'Ankur', 'was\n', 'unaffected', 'by', 'these', 'events.\n']
print(re.sub(r'\n\s+', '\n',' '.join(newContents)))
```

The output:

```
The crazy panda walked to the Maulik and then picked. A nearby Ankur was
unaffected by these events.
```

The above will also remove multiple spaces(if occur) after newline

Answer (score -1):

Strip the whitespace from each one:

```
>>> newContents = ['The', 'crazy', 'panda', 'walked', 'to', 'the', 'Maulik', 'and', 'then', 'picked.', 'A', 'nearby', 'Ankur', 'was\n', 'unaffected', 'by', 'these', 'events.\n']
>>> print(' '.join(item.strip() for item in newContents))
The crazy panda walked to the Maulik and then picked. A nearby Ankur was unaffected by these events.
```

Comment: you do not need to create the list. Just provide an iterator like `' '.join(x.strip() for x in newContents)`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis - `str.join` sometimes performs better when passed a list. That said, this answer is wrong, because it removes the linefeeds. The question only wants to get rid of the extraneous spaces.

Comment: As stated in comments, OP wants to keep newline. Just don't want the space before newline

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That is very interesting.. Do you by any chance have a reference for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822676/joining-strings-generator-or-list-comprehension