# Removing trailing dash from a randomly generated key

Tags: python, random, conditional-statements

So using the code i have when generating a number/letter string it generates an extra dash on the end and i want it to only consist of 16 digits numbers and letters (without the extra dash)

```
import string, random

def generateCode():
    code = ''
    for i in xrange(16):
        number = random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
        code += str(number)
        if (i - 3) % 4 == 0 and i - 4:
            code += '-'

    file = open('AlphaKeys.txt', 'w')
    file.write(code + '\n')
    file.close()
    return code

generateCode()
```

And an example of the output: qIss-wXbS-PZo7-audg-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second condition in your `if` statement serves no meaningful purpose. You should just modify it so as to not add the `-` if you're at the last iteration:

```
if (i - 3) % 4 == 0 and i < 15:
    ...
```

Making this change gives me:

```
LjIs-6HT5-zZMD-HMMz
```

---

Might I suggest an improvement over your current approach with [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample)?

```
import random

r = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
string =  '-'.join(''.join(random.sample(r, 4)) for _ in range(4))
print(string)

'fiqc-fvbc-z7s9-62w3'
```

Note that `random.sample` does not offer replacement per call, so if you want that, you'll need `random.choice`.

If you want randomness with replacement, you can substitute `random.sample` with [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) - but only from python3.6 and onwards.

Comment: OP, note the use of the second approach if you don't mind that groups are unique.

Comment: `random.sample` is wrong in this case. It could be replaced by `random.choices`, but it requires Python 3.6

Comment: @EricDuminil Not wrong, it depends on OP's needs... :) And thanks, I've edited that in.

Comment: Since it's a key, it's probably best to have as many possible keys as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you're adding the dash even at the last iteration.

Anyway, the most pythonic way: just nest 2 `str.join` statements:

```
import string,random

code = "-".join(["".join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for _ in range(4)]) for _ in range(4)])

print(code)
```

an example:

```
m7b1-A0vS-JARQ-hlo2
```

the inner comprension generates the 4 letter/digit sequence, and the outer one joins 4 of those sequences with `-`.

Note that the `join([..])` syntax may appear cumbersome, but is faster than without the square brackets ([Joining strings. Generator or list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822676/joining-strings-generator-or-list-comprehension))

EDIT: note that your digits/letters can repeat with `random.choice`. A better approach without repeats would be to use `random.choice` as follows:

```
import string,random

it = iter(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits,16))

code = "".join(["-" if i % 5 == 4 else next(it) for i in range(19)])
```

the iterator is consumed except when it's time to issue a dash.

Comment: "_but is faster than without the square brackets._" That's interesting...

Comment: That's interesting.. but if Ray says it, then it is truth.

Comment: This also gets a bit more elegant in 3.6, eg: `'-'.join(random.choices(whatever, k=4) for _ in range(4))`...

Comment: @JonClements I've stopped at python 3.4 :) btw I lifted this `iter` or not trick from one of your answers (sorting odd numbers of a list, something like that)

Comment: Wow... listening to me - sounds risky... :p

Comment: most of the time it's okay though :)

Comment: Also... another approach, but overkill here, is you could set up a template string with values to be filled - `replacement = {'X': lambda: random.choice(all_of_them), 'U': lambda L: random.choice(ascii_uppercase), 'L': lambda L: random.choice(ascii_lowercase); output = ''.join(replacement.get(ch, lambda L: ch)(ch) for ch in 'XXXU-LLUX-XLUU-XXXX')` - you get the idea...

Comment: overkill but nice. now looks like a bloody microsoft serial :)

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative, with only one loop :

```
import string,random
possible_chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
"".join(random.choice(possible_chars) if i % 5 < 4 else '-' for i in range(19))
#=> '4Mhg-flw1-lUEu-pu3h'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to add the code that adds the dash before adding the number. eg.

```
if i and i % 4 == 0:
     code+= '-'
number = random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits)
code += str(number)
```

which is a bit more readable than doing it after with

`if (i - 3) % 4 == 0 and i < 15: code+= '-'`

but in general using join would be the more pythonic way eg.

```
def code_part():
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) 
                   for i in xrange(4))
'-'.join(code_part() for i in xrange(4))
```