# Most efficient way to join strings in Python

Tags: python, string, join, optimization, list-comprehension

During the interview, I was given a piece of Python code:

```
"".join([x for x in "\x63\x6c\x75\x62"])
```

The interviewer asked me: Can you make this piece of code faster with just a tiny tweak to the existing code? The output should stay exactly the same.

Enough to say, I failed this question. I'm wondering if anything could help me understand how to optimize this code?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: just `"\x63\x6c\x75\x62"` (join the club, very funny).

Comment: There's no output in that code, so you can delete that line

Comment: I am curious was that interview in front of a python interpreter or just written down on a paper?

Comment: Written down on paper.

Comment: @YannicHamann it's a good question, I think.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
%%timeit
"".join([x for x in "\x63\x6c\x75\x62"])
289 ns ± 3.54 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Outputs `club`.

```
%%timeit 
"".join(["\x63\x6c\x75\x62"])  
66.8 ns ± 0.46 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Outputs `club`.

[x for x...] is useless here. Removing it makes the code running 4 times faster.

Answer (score 11):

```
"".join([x for x in "\x63\x6c\x75\x62"])
```

is a very redundant way of doing:

```
"\x63\x6c\x75\x62"
```

In general, you should not do

```
x for x in "\x63\x6c\x75\x62"
```

this is useless because you don't transform or filter `x` in any way (and it's of course slower).

One last thing, if the interviewer meant to remove the `[]` he/she was also wrong.

```
"".join(x for x in "\x63\x6c\x75\x62")
```

is slower that *with* the listcomp because `join` has to build a `list` anyway (useful to remember this when creating *useful* comprehension, unlike that one, see [Joining strings. Generator or list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822676/joining-strings-generator-or-list-comprehension))

Conclusion: let's *not* join the `club`

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the generator bit

Comment: Very interesting point about the generator. Hadn't thought of that.

Comment: So what exactly is the overhead on the generator expression? ``Join`` casts the generator to a list. So we can skip the creation of the generator entirely and save time by that?

Comment: the provided link explains it more in detail. Creating a list comprehension and providing it to `join` is faster than having `join` force iteration on the generator to create an internal list (iteration call overhead)

Comment: I looked at it, so I guess its both combined. You don't have to create a generator, which is useless in this case since you could directly pass the list, and therefore you don't have to do the extra cast and iterate over it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to do:

```
>>> res = "\x63\x6c\x75\x62"
>>> res
'club'
```

It just a different way to enter the sting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, what about this version?

```
"".join(* ["\x63\x6c\x75\x62"])
```