# Print Hex With Spaces Between

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I'm trying to print my hex out in another way...

First I'm converting this (bytestring is the name of the variable):

```
b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff'
```

to hex,

```
print(bytestring.hex())
```

which outputs:

```
ff00ffffff
```

but I've been trying for a while to get it to output this:

```
ff 00 ff ff ff
```

but no luck.

Any suggestions?
Cheers!

---

Update:

```
stringdata = f.read(5)
print(stringdata)
#b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff'

readHex = " ".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in stringdata.hex()])
# ValueError: Unknown format code 'x' for object of type 'str'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks) or [Split string every nth character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character)

Comment: b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\' is a syntax error: one backslash too many in the end

Comment: @pault: if you consider the intermediate step of the hex string, yes it may be a dupe, but for the whole problem it isn't

Comment: sure- I was thinking `btyestring = str(b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff').encode('hex')` and then you can do `" ".join([btyestring[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(btyestring), 2)])` @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 12, accepted):

just convert your array of bytes to hex strings, and join the result with space:

```
>>> d=b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff'
>>> " ".join(["{:02x}".format(x) for x in d])
'ff 00 ff ff ff'
```

note that `" ".join("{:02x}".format(x) for x in d)` would also work, but forcing the list creation is faster as explained here: [Joining strings. Generator or list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822676/joining-strings-generator-or-list-comprehension)

In python 2, `bytes` is `str` so you have to use `ord` to get character code

```
>>> " ".join(["{:02x}".format(ord(x)) for x in d])
```

Answer (score 17):

In Python 3.8+, `hex` function has an optional argument splitter.

```
>>> print(b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff'.hex(' '))
'ff 00 ff ff ff'
```

And you can split the hex string with any character you want.

```
>>> print(b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff'.hex(':'))
'ff:00:ff:ff:ff'
```

Comment: There's a 2nd parameter that sets bytes per separator, the default is 1. If you make it negative it counts separators from the right, instead of the left.

[docs: hex\(\[sep\[, bytes_per_sep\]\]\)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the byte string and get a series of bytes in python.  These bytes are represented as integers.  You then convert them back to hex strings and join them all together with a space between each hex string.

```
>>> a = b'\xff\x00\xff\xff'
>>> print( ' '.join( '%02x' % x for x in a ) )
'ff 00 ff ff'
```

Or using `format` in python3:

```
>>> a = b'\xff\x00\xff\xff'
>>> print( ' '.join( '{:02x}'.format(x) for x in a ) )
'ff 00 ff ff'
```

Comment: How is this different than the other answer?

Comment: It's not, I was adding it at the same time as Jean-Francois's answer.  I agree with him that joining a list comprehension is probably faster that joining a generator comprehension.  But I like the elegance of generator comprehensions in a function call (if you know the list doesn't have many elements).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a string:

```
bytestring = str(b'\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff').encode('hex')
print(bytestring)
#ff00ffffff
```

Then [iterate over it in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475241/split-string-every-nth-character) of 2, and join the chunks with a space:

```
print(" ".join([bytestring[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(bytestring), 2)]))
#'ff 00 ff ff ff'
```

Comment: Not in Python 3.8: `LookupError: 'hex' is not a text encoding; use codecs.encode() to handle arbitrary codecs`