# Replacing each character in a string using an index into a list

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have a string as follows:

```
mystr = "MY VALUES ARE: (?, ?, ?, ?)"
values = ['a', 'b', 'f', 12]
```

I would like replace each `?` with the corresponding value at that index in the list: `values`. So first `?` would be replaced with `values[0]`, second `?` would be replaced with `values[1]`

So my final str would look like:

```
MY VALUES ARE: ('a', 'b', 'f', '12')
```

> NOTE: The number of `?` will vary but it will always equal the number
>   of values in `values`

Comment: You're leaving yourself open to SQL injection. Don't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the `?` with `{}` and call `format`:

```
print(mystr.replace("?", "'{}'").format(*values))
#MY VALUES ARE: ('a', 'b', 'f', '12')
```

Answer (score 2):

> This isn't sql, this just looks like it. Don't worry about SQL injection, it's not a concern here.

See https://bobby-tables.com/python for parametrized queries - for simply replacement use  [`str.replace(old, new, count=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
sql = "My VALUES are (?, ?, ?, ?)"
values = ['a', 'b', 'f', 12]

for v in values:
    sql = sql.replace("?",f"'{v}'",1)  # inefficient - will create intermediate strings to
                                       # be replaced

print(sql)
```

Output:

My VALUES are ('a', 'b', 'f', '12')

---

Slightly more performant but more code as well:

```
sql = "My VALUES are (?, ?, ?, ?)"
values = ['a', 'b', 'f', 12]

k = iter(values)

# see list comp below for shorter approach
l = []  
for c in sql:
    if c != '?':
        l.append(c)
    else:
        l.append(f"'{next(k)}'")

sql = "".join(l)
print(sql)         # My VALUES are ('a', 'b', 'f', '12') as well
```

As list comprehension ([join is faster on list then on generator comps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822788/6162307)) thx [@Ev. Kuonis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6162307/ev-kounis) :

```
sql = "".join( [ c if c != '?' else f"'{next(k)}'" for c in sql] )
```

Comment: the list comprehension version of the second snippet would not be as big.

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic but [we have it on good authority](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822788/6162307) that `join` is faster with list comprehensions than generators.

Comment: I reacted the same way when I found out :))