# Mapping list of functions to list of items element-wise

Tags: python, algorithm, mapping

I have 3 functions (`f1`, `f2` and `f3`) that each take an input and return a `str`.

These functions are stored in a list in an order that is determined by settings in a program prior to receiving inputs. Their ordering may be different each time a program is run:

```
# User A's run:
funcs = [f1, f1, f2, f1, f3]

# User B's run:
funcs = [f3, f3, f2]
```

During program execution, a list of inputs will be generated that correspond the to ordering of `funcs`. That is to say, the item type of each index in the list `inputs` will be the correct type expected by the function at the corresponding index of `funcs`:

```
# f1 expects int
# f2 expects float
# f3 expects str

funcs = [f1, f1, f2, f1, f3]
inputs = [0, 1, 3.14, 10, 'abc']
```

I need to map `funcs` to `inputs` element-wise and concatenate the resulting string. Currently I solve this by using `zip`:

```
result = ''.join(f(i) for f, i in zip(func, inputs))
```

Is there another way to achieve this type of mapping or is `zip` the ideal way?

Comment: zip seems to be the most efficient way; you could loop through and do per item in the funcs list, but your implementation is cleaner.

Comment: The only potentially better way I see is to replace the generator with a list comprehension for efficiency.

Comment: `zip` works and is clear.  People will disagree on what is "ideal".

Comment: @superbrain in what way would a list comprehension be more efficient? the generator is obviously memory efficient, but does `join()` perform better with a list comprehension? *Edit*: found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34822788/7811364) post that explains an explicit conversion in the implementation.

Comment: @pasta_sauce Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/13008439).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can import FunctionType and map each function to each input directly (tried it with a list of lambdas and it does work):

```
from types import FunctionType
funcs = [f1,f1,f2,f1,f3]
inputs = [0, 1, 3.14, 10, 'abc']
"".join(map(FunctionType.__call__, funcs, inputs))
```