# What type of iterable is "x for x in y"?

Tags: python, generator, iterable, generator-expression

I've been confused of list comprehension in Python, although its shorthand doing for loop is very convenient.  I'm not sure if what's in the `join()` function's parameter below is list comprehension since usually you put `[]` around to show it's a list comprehension.

My question: What's the type of iterable produced by `str(x) for x in res[::-1]` in `join()` below? Thanks.

ex,

```
''.join( str(x) for x in res[::-1] )
```

Comment: "although its shorthand doing for loop is very convenient"—comprehensions are _not_ a shorthand for loops. Loops and comprehensions are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), which itself is an iterable.

The square brackets could still be added, however. Refer [Joining strings. Generator or list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822676/joining-strings-generator-or-list-comprehension)

Comment: It might be worth adding that `str.join()` is special, and normally you wouldn't want to add the brackets, like with `sum`, `min`/`max`, `any`/`all`, etc.